# Will these optocoupler configuration work to tri-state high voltage GPIOS?

Tags: led, gpio, tri-state, charlieplexing

I am trying to control an array of LEDs that require a very high voltage due to the high impedance of the connections (there is no option to change that).

Since the charlieplex configuration makes use of the tri-state logic, I need to design a system that allows me to obtain the **HIGH**, **LOW** and **HIGH-Z** states through a microcontroller without burning the GPIOS. That is why I have dealt with BJTs, MOSFETS and comparators without having good luck.

Now, what I present below is the last alternative that I have been evaluating, which in the simulations has proven to work perfectly. This consists of an arrangement of three optocouplers, two used to define the HIGH and LOW state through a single GPIO (1, 3 and 5) and a second optocoupler that allows the HIGH-Z state to be defined through a second GPIO (2, 4 and 6).

My question is, is the design right? Should I consider any particular variable in an optocoupler design?

[image: Diagram 1]

This diagram is basically a low pass filter to increase the activation threshold a bit and avoid activation by ESD or noise (resistance) and attenuate spikes and transient suppression (capacitor). The switches are only to see the changes while the simulation runs. I don't plan on using physical switches in the design.

[image: Diagram 2]

So far I have not seen a single design on the web that uses optocouplers or even optical SSRs to obtain a tri-state logic. So I do not know if I am doing an electronic aberration or this may be something useful.

thanks for any feedback.

EDIT: The total amount of pins of the Charlieplexed array is around 8, thus 16 GPIO, 50±5 LEDs, and 30 optocouplers.

Comment: The inverters and U10 - U12 are redundant. You could control the other optocouplers independently using the same 2 GPIO pins per pair, to get the desired result more efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optocoupler design has a couple issues besides requiring lots of board space.  The biggest is that you're expecting U10--U12 to sink current into the emitter, which is out of spec.  Another is that when GPIO 1 goes from low to high, U1 and U2 present a brief short from VCC to ground.  Your LPs should be removed since they are actually high passes, and the optocouplers are fairly noise-immune anyway due to hysteresis and being current controlled.

A solution that fits well would be to use the TMUX7219.  It works with ~TTL input levels, can switch over 100mA bidirectional at 44V, has an on resistance of a few ohms only, a high z state, and in low z switches between two sources, in your case +12 and 0V.

Comment: Hi Carsten, thanks for your answer.

yes, the shoot-through current is something I'm currently assessing, maybe I can do a coding trick or change that two optocoupler array for a push/pull transistor configuration.

With respect to the size, you can find optocouplers with a footprint of [2x2 mm](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/panasonic-electric-works/AQY2C1R2PX/5284329). Nonetheless, this is an SSR. 

I will definitely give a look to the TMUX. thanks